# pyautogui not working on MacOS ('<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int')

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui, image-recognition

I`m trying to find an image on the screen using pyautoGUI on MacOS. The code i use is the following:

```
import pyautogui

img = 'name.png'

img = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(img)
```

Can anyone help me? I was expecting to get the coordinates of the image, instead i got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cliente/Documents/Personal/dofusBot/bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    img = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(img)
  File "/Users/cliente/miniconda/envs/analytics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 172, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cliente/miniconda/envs/analytics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 204, in locateCenterOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cliente/miniconda/envs/analytics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 420, in locateCenterOnScreen
    coords = locateOnScreen(image, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cliente/miniconda/envs/analytics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 375, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(
  File "/Users/cliente/miniconda/envs/analytics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 527, in _screenshot_osx
    if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: You didn't include the entire stacktrace, which would have had a lot of useful information.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman sorry, I`m new here, I put it now, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like a "bug" in pyscreeze due to it not keeping up with the past few years of updates to the Pillow library (PIL) and makes a faulty assumption on how the version variable is defined in that library.

The developer of pyscreeze seems to have addressed this 2 months ago in commit [eeca245a135cf171c163b3691300138518efa64e](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/commit/eeca245a135cf171c163b3691300138518efa64e) but have not yet made any new release. You could install pyscreeze from source, or just sneakily patch your installation (it's just one `__init__.py` file).

It might also work if you downgrade Pillow a few versions (but I'm not sure how far back you need to go. Presumably no further than 6.2.1, but that's 4 years old).

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work changing line 527 from

```
if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):
```

just to

```
if False:
```

Before doing this however, you should check your PIL__version__ (you can jsut insert a print(PIL__version__))
If it is less than 6.2.1 set it to

```
if True:
```

but otherwise just do what I did. Hope this helps!